# Detecting Google Bot to hide content - dangerous?

Tags: hide, googlebot

I've been looking into various ways to reduce duplicate content on a client's website.

One method I've come across is using some code to check whether the client is a certain bot, or not.  Using this information one can choose to display information to the client, or not.

Would this method be dangerous to use with Google for any reason?

Here's the code (PHP), for information:

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what you mean by "dangerous".

You are not disallowed to block web crawlers from going through your website if that is your intention AFAIK, you could easily do this with "robots.txt" instead of PHP implementation though.

However, if by "dangerous" you mean security exploits, then of course there is the whole deal with user agent spoofing, so I wouldn't advise to say give away more data than you would want just basing it on what user agent the request is hiding behind because that can be faked.

Comment: When I say dangerous, I mean would it be frowned upon (if detected) in Google's eyes?  This is page content level inclusion/exclusion, which cannot be achieved with robots.txt. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I don't think that Google will particularly care if you include/exclude content for when their crawlers are traversing your site, however this might affect how your site is displayed from Google's perspective (for example when other people query Google for your page). Therefore if you exclude some content from the GoogleBot that content might not appear on Google (since technically it didn't see it when it was looking around). On the other hand if you include some content for GoogleBot that regular users cannot access, you might mislead people wanting to find something that is not there.